# MYSQL Group By date + 3 hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query that counts the "Xp" difference per day from my database, this all works as it should however it groups from midnight-midnight, what I would like to do is group 3am to 3am.

However another issue I think I may have is that my query may not always have the rows being the exact second at 3am due to the fact that it has to run a huge query and retrieve data from another website per user profile, so it should get all data after 3am, but before maybe 4am or something, so it has enough time to get all of the rows.

my current mysql is:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y%m%d') AS YYYYMMDD, MAX(xp)-MIN(xp) AS xp_gain
FROM skills
WHERE userID = '$checkID'
AND skill = '$skill'
AND date >= '$date'
GROUP BY YYYYMMDD
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to add (if you can) another column that is just a DATE (not a DATETIME) and have this field rollover from one day to the next at 3am, (you can to this by subtracting 3 hours from the current time when doing the INSERT).

This gives you a couple of benefits, especially with a large number of rows:

- It is much faster to query or group by a DATE than a range of
  DATETIME
- It will always query the rows at the exact second of 3am,
  regardless of how long the query takes.